# Panel/text not being responsive in bootstrap 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had this before

```
<div class="panel panel-default" >
<div class="panel-body">
```

but my panel was way to wide for my text inside it, so I changed it to

```
<div class="panel panel-bg" style= "width: 700px">
<div class = "panel-body">
```

yet now the entire panel and its code has lost its responsiveness to scree resizing...

any ideas?

Comment: You have to use max-width:700px as the fastest way, though you should learn some responsive css and make media queries for this type of stuff

Comment: Also, don't use inline styles. Create your own CSS file, include it below the bootstrap.css file.